# New-PSDrive : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Root' because it is null

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am trying to run a PowerShell script on local machine. The agenda of this script is to connect multiple shared drives using the CSV file and get the size of the shared drive and then export to result.csv. I have executed line by line, but I'm getting the following error:

> New-PSDrive : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Root' because it is null.

```bsh
Function CleanUp-PSDrive {
    Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem |
        Where { $_.Name -in (69..90 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ }) } |
        Remove-PSDrive
}

$Csv = Import-Csv "path"

$Csv.Name | ForEach-Object -Begin { $Letter = 69 } {
    New-PSdrive -Root $_ -Name ([char]$Letter) -PSProvider FileSystem

    #Do some stuff...

    if ($Letter -lt 90) {
        $Letter++ 
    } else {
        CleanUp-PSDrive
        $Letter = 69
    }
} -End { CleanUp-PSDrive }
```

Comment: Please show the output of `$Csv.Name | % {"-$_-"}`.

Comment: PS C:\windows\system32> $Csv.Name | ForEach-Object -Begin { $Letter = 69 }
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:

Comment: Iam trying to run powershell script on local machine. The agenda of this script is " I would like to connect multiple shared drives using the csv file and get the size of the shared drive and then export to result.csv. I have executed line by line only getting error to below line only " New-PSDrive : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Root' because it is null.
"

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't clear enough the first time around. **Please show the output of `$Csv.Name | % {"-$_-"}`.**

Comment: $Csv.Name | ForEach-Object -Begin { $Letter = 69 }
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:

Comment: Does `$Csv.Name | ForEach-Object -Begin { $Letter = 69 }` somehow look like `$Csv.Name | % {"-$_-"}` to you? Please DO NOT get creative. Run the *exact* command I asked you to run.

Comment: PS C:\windows\system32> $Csv.Name | % {"-$_-"}
--
--

Comment: Your CSV has empty rows, or it doesn't have a column titled "Name".

Comment: Thanks... It worked.. but didn't get the used space and also free space of the disk and also the file is not exporting to the text file. can you please help me? I am new to Powershell. Thanks for the help

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Either rewrite this question (since no answer has been posted yet), or post a new one. Either way, make sure the question shows a [mcve] of your current code.